# Double precision strange behaviour. Need an explanation

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

static double const x = 665857;
static double const y = 470832;

int main(){
    double z = x*x*x*x -(y*y*y*y*4+y*y*4);
    printf("%f \n",z);
    return 0;
}
```

Mysteriously (to me) this code prints "0.0" if compiled on 32 bits machines (or with the -m32 flag on 64 bits machines like in my case) with GCC 4.6. As far as I know about floating point operations, it is possible to overflow/underflow them or to lose precision with them, but... a 0? How?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Overflowing a `double` is undefined behaviour, no? If so, it's no wonder you got a 0.

Comment: x86 comes from the processor series. Don't confuse that with 64-bits. You have x86-32 bits processors and x86-64.

Comment: The words you are looking for are “catastrophic cancellation”. See the introduction of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: IIRC, floating point encoding supports the overflow state (just like infinite and NaN), it's not an undefined.

Comment: Also, you don't need `#include <math.h>`. But I'm just being pedantic. And `int main(void)` if this is supposed to be valid C.

Comment: Edited the title beacuse I really don't know if there's an overflow involved here.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar I hate warnings, but that's just me being a purist :)

Comment: @Hallucynogenyc ok thanks, I don't really use floating points much :)

Comment: @SethCarnegie: I'm not sure about what I said, just what I remember :)

Comment: You can also disprove Fermat's Last Theorem like this: printf( "%g\n", pow(6107,6) + pow(8919,6) - pow(9066,6) );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is result of the way IEEE 754 represents floating point numbers in normalized form. float or double or whatever other IEEE 754 compliant representation is stored like:

```
1.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx * 2^exp
```

where `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` is the fractional part of the mantissa so the mantissa itself is always in the range [1, 2). The integer part which is always 1 is not stored in the representation. The number of `x` bits defines the precision. It is 52 bits for the `double`. The exponent is stored in an offset form (one must subtract 1023 in order to obtain its value) but that is irrelevant now.

665857^4 in 64-bit IEEE 754 is:

```
0 10001001100 (1)0100110100000001111100111011101010000101110010100010
+ exponent    mantissa
```

(the first bit is the sign bit: 0 = positive, 1 - negative; the bit in parentheses is not really stored)

In 80-bit x86 extended precision it is:

```
0 10001001100    (1)0100110100000001111100111011101010000101110010100010
0 100000001001100 1 010011010000000111110011101110101000010111001010000111000111011
```

(here the integer part is explicitly part of the representation - a deviation from IEEE 754; I've aligned the mantissas for clarity)

4*470832^4 in 64-bit IEEE 754 and 80-bit x86 extended precision is:

```
0 10001001100    (1)0100110100000001111100111011101001111111010101100111
0 100000001001100 1 010011010000000111110011101110100111111101010110011100100010000
```

4*470832^2 in 64-bit IEEE 754 and 80-bit x86 extended precision is:

```
0 10000100110    (1)1001110011101010100101010100100000000000000000000000
0 100000000100110 1 100111001110101010010101010010000000000000000000000000000000000
```

When you sum up the last two numbers, the procedure is the following: the smaller value has its exponent adjusted to match the larger value's exponent while the mantissa is shifted to the right in order to preserve the value. Since the two exponents differ by 38, the mantissa of the smaller number is shifted 38 bits to the right:

470832^2*4 in adjusted 64-bit IEEE 754 and 80-bit x86 extended precision:

```
 this bit came from 1.xxxx ------------------------------v
0 10001001100    (0)0000000000000000000000000000000000000110011100111010|1010
0 100000001001100 0 0000000000000000000000000000000000000110011100111010101001010101
```

Now both quantities have the same exponents and their mantissas could be summed:

```
0 10001001100 (1)0100110100000001111100111011101001111111010101100111|0010
0 10001001100 (0)0000000000000000000000000000000000000110011100111010|1010
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
0 10001001100 (1)0100110100000001111100111011101010000101110010100001|1100
```

I kept some of the 80-bit precision bits on the right of the bar, because the summation internally is done in the greater precision of 80 bits.

Now let's perform the subtraction in 64-bit + some bits of the 80-bit rep:

```
minuend    0 10001001100 (1)0100110100000001111100111011101010000101110010100001|1100
subtrahend 0 10001001100 (1)0100110100000001111100111011101010000101110010100001|1100
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
difference 0 10001001100 (0)0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000|0000
```

A pure 0! If you perform the calculations in full 80-bit, you would once again obtain a pure 0.

The real problem here is that 1.0 cannot be represented in 64-bit precision with an exponent of 2^77 - there are no 77 bits of precision in the mantissa. This is also true for the 80-bit precision - there are only 63 bits in the mantissa, 14 bits less than necessary to represent 1.0 given an exponent of 2^77.

So that's it! It's just the wonderful world of scientific computing where nothing works the way you were taught in the math classes...

Comment: While I'm heavily impressed by the work you just did here, I don't really understand your conclusion. Why is 1.0 not being representable in 77 bits the problem?

Comment: x*x*x*x is 1,96573006004558194713601*10^23, y*y*y*y*4+y*y*4 is 1,96573006004558194713600*10^23. Their difference is 0,00000000000000000000001*10^23. 10^23 is ~2^77 so 0,......1 is ~2^-77. You need 77 bits to represent that mantissa. The 80-bit `long double` on x86 only gives you 63 bits. That's why.

Comment: Ok, now I got it. I'll accept this answer. It came a bit late but definitely the one that put the most effort. Thank you so much.

Comment: “the summation internally is done in the greater precision of 80 bits.” No, the sum is computed with the number of bits targeted for the result, plus three, the last of which is wired specially (“sticky bit”). For the **now obsolete** instructions that compute with 80-bit floating-point numbers, the computation is made with a few more than 64 bits: http://www.engineering.uiowa.edu/~carch/lectures07/55035-070404-prn.pdf Note that there is no sign in the question that the OP compiled his program using 80-bit floating-point.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, the default for GCC is to output x87 instructions in 32-bit mode unless specifically instructed to use SSE instead and therefore 80-bit internal precision is used.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is not that the numbers overflow. The problem is that doubles don't have enough precision to distinguish between the two operands of your subtraction.

The value of `x*x*x*x` is 196573006004558194713601.

The value of `y*y*y*y*4+y*y*4` is 196573006004558194713600.

These numbers have 78 bits, and only the last bit is different. Double precision numbers only have 53 bits. Other numbers are rounded to only 53 bits.

In your case, the two operands are rounded to the same number, and so their difference is 0.

Even stranger things happen if you slightly rewrite your expression for z:

```
double z = x * x * x * x - ((y * y + 1) * y * y * 4);
```

With this change, you get 33554432! Why? Because the way intermediate results were rounded caused the last bit of the right operand to be different. The value of the last bit is 2^(78-53)=2^25.

Answer (score 6):

Evaluating the expression with arbitrary precision integers:

```
Prelude> 665857^4 - 4*(470832^4 + 470832^2)
1
```

Since a `double` normally only has 53 bits of precision and the intermediate results have 78 bits, the precision isn't sufficient to calculate the result exactly, hence it is rounded, the last bits are forgotten at some point.

Answer (score 4):

There is no floating-point overflow or underflow in your code. The two quantities are of the order of 1.96573006 × 10^23, and largely fit within a `double`. Your example simply illustrates catastrophic cancellation, where you subtract two close quantities and the relative precision of the result becomes horrible.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance

Comment: No, the two operands of the subtraction are *equal*. Otherwise you would not get a zero result. This has nothing to do with catastrophic cancellation but with loss of precision in the computation of the expressions on each side of the minus sign.

Comment: @R.. I mean the two quantities computed as reals. The `double`s that represent them in the program have each good relative precision—although, as you point out, they are equal but represent unequal quantities. Their `double` difference does not have good relative precision, therefore, the subtraction is, from the point of view of numerical stability, the culprit. This is catastrophic cancellation just like the quadratic equation example on the Wikipedia page is still catastrophic cancellation when it happens that the `double` for b^2 is equal to the `double` for 4ac, and not just close to it.

Comment: No, seriously, how is the case of two quantities being **equal** not an example of a general trap to watch for when two quantities are **close**? It does not have “nothing” to do with catastrophic cancellation. It is the ultimate example of catastrophic cancellation.

Comment: @R.. Okay, I finally got what you and the two persons who upvoted your comment disagree about. Your argument is that the subtraction is exact. **Catastrophic cancellation has nothing to do with whether the floating-point subtraction happens to be exact.** Catastrophic cancellation is when the relative error of the result is catastrophically worse than the relative error of the arguments (see wikipedia page). The notion of relative error on the arguments means that it doesn't matter a bit that the `double` subtraction is exact. The `double` operands are already approximations of something else.